# Determine if month of date falls on a quarter of date

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I need to write some SQL that will determine if the current month is based on a quarter from a specified date.

If I give it '2015-04-09', the function should determine if the month is equal to 1, 4, 7, or 10. If I give it '2015-05-09', it will be 2, 5, 8, 11. Etc...

It would work best if the entire solution is self contained within the SELECT statement. I'm not quite sure how to approach this and I couldn't really find anything that fit my situation. I don't care about the day or the year, I just need to verify the month.

Comment: I do not understand your requirements...

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to know when this expression is true:

```
(mod(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM SYSDATE()), 3)) = (mod(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM <input date>), 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the month using `month()` and then use modulo arithmetic.  Something like this:

```
select (case when mod(month($input) - month($thedate), 3) = 0 then 1
             else 0
        end)
```

Comment: @MaciejLos, The quarter function returns the quarter of the given date, which is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Thanks, I was not aware that it was called 'modular' arithmetic, I always thought it was called modulo arithmetic and the result was the modulus.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a quarter number, and you want to get starting month of a quarter:

```
QuarterNo * 3 - 2
```

If you want to get quarter number, given the month number:

```
floor((MonthNo-1) /3) +1
```

If you have date column, and you want quarter number then use:

```
DATEPART(qurter, date_column)
```